# How to make post requests work with ngrok?

Tags: python, flask, post, request, ngrok

I am using python to develop an application. I am doing some tests to see how it works.

First I tried this code with Flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'The GET works'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And it worked fine. Then, because I want everyone to access my application, I used ngrok for that, I just typed in the console:

```
./ngrok http 5000
```

And it worked fine, I can access the URL from everywhere, but for my application, I need to be able to make POST requests from everywhere. But whenever I try to make a post request like this

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://10d2b892.ngrok.io/',data={'key':'value'})
```

r returns Response [405] and I cant post anything.
What should I do in order to make Post requests work?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/), you should use annotations:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return do_the_login()
    else:
        return show_the_login_form()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngrok` will forward whatever http request you send it. Your problem is that the Flask application isn't written to handle post requests. On that note, I will assume you're new to Flask and will recommend you to just do the switch to FastAPI immediately:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', status_code=200)
def index():
    return {'message':'Hello, World!'}

@app.post('/', status_code=201)
def index_post():
    return {'message':'Hello, Post!'}
```

I believe it will make your life easier in both the short and long run. If you also run it using Uvicorn you'll be off to a good start:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', status_code=200)
def index():
    return {'message':'Hello, World!'}

@app.post('/', status_code=201)
def index_post():
    return {'message':'Hello, Post!'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "views:app", 
        host="localhost", 
        port=5000,
        reload=True    
    )
```

Go ahead and name that file `views.py`.

Create your virtual environment (venv):

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
```

Source it

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
```

Install the modules

```sh
pip install uvicorn fastapi
```

and run it

```sh
python views.py
```

Now you can make it accessible with ngrok

```
ngrok http 5000
```

When you save changes in `views.py` your uvicorn server will restart automatically, and you should be able to try your changes out without restarting anything.

Hope this gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The annotation you're using

```
@app.route("/")
```

creates a default route with the `GET` method, but you're trying to `POST`. Since you didn't define `POST`, you get a `405 Method Not Allowed`. To fix that, simply define `POST`, as documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

As an added bonus, you can also manage `ngrok` in your Python script using `pyngrok`. There's a Flask documented example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), but the short if it is you'd simply do `from pyngrok import ngrok` and `ngrok.connect(5000)`. Boom, now you have a tunnel to the Flask dev server.